# AFJSONParameterEncoding makes the data the entire key and there is no value

Tags: ios, django, json, afnetworking

Good afternoon!

I am trying to do a simple POST request and sending over my parameters as JSON to my Django server. Here is the code:

```
    NSDictionary* params = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"TestContent", @"content", nil];

    [[objectManager HTTPClient]setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];


    [[objectManager HTTPClient]postPath:@"/api/rest/content/add/" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     { ...}
```

Back on my Django, the request.POST looks like this:

```
print >> sys.stderr, "%s" % request.POST
```

Outputs

```
<QueryDict: {u'{"content":"TestContent"}': [u'']}>
```

As if the entire JSON was the "key" of the request.POST. Why is it doing that?! How can I make use of this?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not form-encoded data, so don't use `request.POST`. Use `request.body` to access the data instead.

Comment: Well that worked... wow. So, should I always be using         [[objectManager HTTPClient]setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];? Is it safer? Pros and cons?

Thanks again!